# TLS Error: Handshake failed. Openvpn Server is behind NAT on dynamic ip

Tags: iptables, firewall, openvpn, tls, tcpdump

this is a [common](http://TLS%20Error:%20Handshake%20failed.Server%20is%20behind%20NAT%20on%20dyn%20ip) problem that appears easily in searches and seems to be related to the firewall , yet I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. I have actually asked [before](https://serverfault.com/questions/679338/openvpn-tls-handshake-fails-on-client-because-firewall-drops-packets-but-why), but this time I come back with more info on the matter and a better understanding of the problem.

The problem appears when my openvpn server (which sits behind a NAT) has its external IP changed, since my internet connection has a dynamic ip.

SO, as soon as my external ip changes, my vpn clients can no longer connect to the server. It is a headache, because after a restart (of the openvpn server and perhaps the firewall as well) things usually are not corrected. After a few restarts though things will get working for a few days until my ip changes again.

The following logs have been acquired from 2 (server & a client) slackware linux systems.

My server config is the following:

```
cd /etc/openvpn
proto udp
port 32456
comp-lzo
verb 1
log-append /var/log/openvpn/server.log
status /var/log/openvpn/server-status.log
daemon
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
server 192.168.26.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
client-to-client
client-config-dir ccd
route-gateway 'dhcp'
route 192.168.114.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.18.0 255.255.255.0
push "route 192.168.112.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway"
push "route 192.168.114.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.18.0 255.255.255.0"
cipher BF-CBC
ca keys/ca.crt
dh keys/dh1024.pem
cert keys/stardust.crt
key keys/stardust.key
crl-verify certs/crl.pem
keepalive 20 120
user openvpn
group openvpn
max-clients 15
```

and the client config is the following (same across all clients)

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote my.dyndns1.site 32456
remote mydyndns2.site 32456
float
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/forge.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/forge.key
ns-cert-type server
cipher BF-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
mute 10
keepalive 10 60
log-append /var/log/openvpn/client.log
```

on the server , the log files states the following ()

```
Mon Jul 13 17:27:43 2015 us=15365 x.x.x.x:39397 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Mon Jul 13 17:27:43 2015 us=15406 x.x.x.x:39397 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
....
....(a few seconds pass by)
....
Mon Jul 13 17:29:43 2015 us=15492 x.x.x.x:39397 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
Mon Jul 13 17:29:44 2015 us=718669 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Mon Jul 13 17:29:44 2015 us=718735 x.x.x.x:47092 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Mon Jul 13 17:29:44 2015 us=718770 x.x.x.x:47092 LZO compression initialized
Mon Jul 13 17:29:44 2015 us=718856 x.x.x.x:47092 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Mon Jul 13 17:29:44 2015 us=718888 x.x.x.x:47092 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Mon Jul 13 17:29:44 2015 us=718932 x.x.x.x:47092 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1542,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SH
A1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Mon Jul 13 17:29:44 2015 us=718948 x.x.x.x:47092 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1542,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher BF-C
BC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
Mon Jul 13 17:29:44 2015 us=718974 x.x.x.x:47092 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '530fdded'
Mon Jul 13 17:29:44 2015 us=718994 x.x.x.x:47092 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '41690919'
Mon Jul 13 17:29:44 2015 us=719028 x.x.x.x:47092 TLS: Initial packet from x.x.x.x:47092, sid=a439532b 854729a0
```

on the client , the log file states:

```
Mon Jul 13 17:32:51 2015 us=341010 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Mon Jul 13 17:32:51 2015 us=341263 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Mon Jul 13 17:32:51 2015 us=341309 LZO compression initialized
Mon Jul 13 17:32:51 2015 us=341451 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:138 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Mon Jul 13 17:32:51 2015 us=341526 Socket Buffers: R=[229376->131072] S=[229376->131072]
Mon Jul 13 17:32:51 2015 us=510459 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1542 D:1450 EF:42 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Mon Jul 13 17:32:51 2015 us=510614 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1542,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128
,key-method 2,tls-client'
Mon Jul 13 17:32:51 2015 us=510642 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1542,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher BF-CBC,auth SHA1,k
eysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Mon Jul 13 17:32:51 2015 us=510692 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '41690919'
Mon Jul 13 17:32:51 2015 us=510733 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '530fdded'
Mon Jul 13 17:32:51 2015 us=510771 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Mon Jul 13 17:32:51 2015 us=510806 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:32456
....
....(a few secs pass by)
....
Mon Jul 13 17:32:49 2015 us=340411 [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Mon Jul 13 17:32:49 2015 us=340678 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Mon Jul 13 17:32:49 2015 us=340752 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Mon Jul 13 17:32:49 2015 us=340792 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
```

do you see anything wrong with my configs?
My guess is that the client firewalls do no allow ping-responses to reach them , once the ip of the server has changed (so all stateful ESTABLISH , RELATED connections no longer apply for the new server ip).

So looking into it I started testing the firewall logs and log the packets between a client and the openvpn server.

with `tcpdump -i eth1 host <server_ip> and udp` from the client side I checked the incoming packets ...

```
17:31:22.467092 IP 192.168.233.165.36312 > <server_ip>.32456: UDP, length 14
17:31:22.510463 IP <server_ip>.13519 > 192.168.233.165.36312: UDP, length 26
17:31:24.553394 IP 192.168.233.165.36312 > <server_ip>.32456: UDP, length 14
17:31:24.595869 IP <server_ip>.13519 > 192.168.233.165.36312: UDP, length 26
```

... while looking at the firewall log as well

```
Jul 15 17:31:22 zeus INPUT packet died: IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:50:bf:2b:5f:f8:20:89:86:9a:f1:10:08:00 SRC=<server_ip> DST=192.168.233.165 LEN=54 TOS=00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=13519 DPT=36312 LEN=34
Jul 15 17:31:24 zeus INPUT packet died: IN=eth1 OUT= MAC=00:50:bf:2b:5f:f8:20:89:86:9a:f1:10:08:00 SRC=<server_ip> DST=192.168.233.165 LEN=54 TOS=00 PREC=0x00 TTL=56 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=13519 DPT=36312 LEN=34
```

Indeed, as per expected the connection is not established because the client firewall INPUT chain, intercepts the server's response. The client firewall looks like

```
iptables -A INPUT -p ALL -i $INET_IFACE -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

so I would expect this line to let the packet through.
I do has stateful packet inspection enabled:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK

CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_MARK=y
# CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_EVENTS is not set
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IPV4=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IPV6=m
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK=m
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_QUEUE=m
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_LOG=m
```

just to verify I also checked

```
cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack | <server_ip>

udp 17 24 src=192.168.233.165 dst=<server_ip> sport=36312 dport=32456 [UNREPLIED] src=<server_ip> dst=192.168.233.165 sport=32456 dport=36312 mark=0 use=2
```

So reading the 2 first lines of tcpdump (taken from the client) the client sends a packet from port 36312 to the designated (in the openvpn server config) port 32456.

Then the client firewall setups up a conntrack rule (for established connection). This is not established yet - i assume the server must reply on the same channel .

BUT (reading back on the tcpdump, 2nd line) the openvpn server replies from port 13519, so this can never get passed the "ESTABLISHED,RELATED" lines.

Am I right to conclude that this is the problem? what can I do about this? There seems to be nothing available in the openvpn server to fix the server response port. And I am not sure about other possible solutions to this problem...

Comment: The solution is a static IP address.

Comment: is this really the Only solution? :(

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your OpenVPN config files. I have lots of successful setups with dynamic IP address (server side & client side in the same time), the problem has to be firewall related.

Comment: Could you get a tcpdump of the connection? What is your configuration like? Are both server and clients behind Nat?

Comment: @MichalSokolowski Could you get a tcpdump of the connection? What is your configuration like? Are both server and clients behind NAT? what are your server and client versions? The problem IS firewall related but unless there is a way to enable "ESTABLISHED,RELATED" connections that do not check the source port, I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, I know, I've just pasted my configs on OPs request.

Client config:

```
remote xxxx.no-ip.info
port 1195
float

# network
dev tun0
ifconfig 192.168.7.98 192.168.7.97
route 192.168.7.64 255.255.255.224 192.168.7.97
route 192.168.7.128 255.255.255.224 192.168.7.97

# symmetrical key
secret /etc/openvpn/scalpel/static.key

# compression
comp-lzo

# Security
user nobody
group nogroup

# high availability options
keepalive 10 30
persist-tun
persist-key
verb 1
mute 2

# Logging
log-append /var/log/openvpn_scalpel.log
```

Server config:

```
# Scalpel - OpenVPN Server (do lacznosci miedzy oddzialami)
# Last modified 2011.05.22

port 1195

# network
dev tun0
ifconfig 192.168.7.97 192.168.7.98
route 192.168.7.0 255.255.255.192 192.168.7.98

# symmetrical key
secret /etc/openvpn/scalpel/static.key

# compression
comp-lzo

# Security
user nobody
group nogroup
max-clients 1 # maximum number to clients allowed to connect

# high availability options
keepalive 10 30
persist-tun
persist-key
verb 1
mute 2

# Logging
log-append /var/log/openvpn_scalpel.log
```

Packet trace server side:

```
  0.000000 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 102 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
  3.834972 192.168.7.66 -> 79.184.15.251 UDP 158 Source port: 1195  Destination port: 5117
  3.927502 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 166 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
  3.930257 192.168.7.66 -> 79.184.15.251 UDP 158 Source port: 1195  Destination port: 5117
  4.022063 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 166 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
  8.223466 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 102 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
 14.436576 192.168.7.66 -> 79.184.15.251 UDP 102 Source port: 1195  Destination port: 5117
 17.929467 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 102 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
 17.929594 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 102 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
 17.929685 192.168.7.66 -> 79.184.15.251 UDP 238 Source port: 1195  Destination port: 5117
 27.989889 192.168.7.66 -> 79.184.15.251 UDP 102 Source port: 1195  Destination port: 5117
 28.081743 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 102 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
 38.104471 192.168.7.66 -> 79.184.15.251 UDP 102 Source port: 1195  Destination port: 5117
 38.207144 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 102 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
 44.063394 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 254 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
 44.063662 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 214 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
 48.249463 192.168.7.66 -> 79.184.15.251 UDP 102 Source port: 1195  Destination port: 5117
 54.440786 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 102 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
 58.703483 192.168.7.66 -> 79.184.15.251 UDP 102 Source port: 1195  Destination port: 5117
Wed Jul 29 14:40:02 2015 read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (code=111)
 68.715974 192.168.7.66 -> 79.184.15.251 UDP 102 Source port: 1195  Destination port: 5117
Wed Jul 29 14:40:12 2015 NOTE: --mute triggered...
 78.984871 192.168.7.66 -> 79.184.15.251 UDP 102 Source port: 1195  Destination port: 5117
Wed Jul 29 14:40:17 2015 1 variation(s) on previous 2 message(s) suppressed by --mute
Wed Jul 29 14:40:17 2015 Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Wed Jul 29 14:40:17 2015 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Wed Jul 29 14:40:19 2015 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Wed Jul 29 14:40:19 2015 Re-using pre-shared static key
Wed Jul 29 14:40:19 2015 LZO compression initialized
Wed Jul 29 14:40:19 2015 Preserving previous TUN/TAP instance: tun0
Wed Jul 29 14:40:19 2015 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]:1195
Wed Jul 29 14:40:19 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
Wed Jul 29 14:40:32 2015 Peer Connection Initiated with 79.184.15.251:5117
 99.482520 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 102 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
Wed Jul 29 14:40:33 2015 Initialization Sequence Completed
106.579960 192.168.7.66 -> 79.184.15.251 UDP 102 Source port: 1195  Destination port: 5117
106.579994 192.168.7.66 -> 79.184.15.251 UDP 102 Source port: 1195  Destination port: 5117
106.671790 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 238 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
110.199108 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 102 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
110.199228 192.168.7.66 -> 79.184.15.251 UDP 238 Source port: 1195  Destination port: 5117
119.683353 79.184.15.251 -> 192.168.7.66 UDP 102 Source port: 5117  Destination port: 1195
120.784617 192.168.7.66 -> 79.184.15.251 UDP 102 Source port: 1195  Destination port: 5117
```

Packet trace client side:

```
  0.000000  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
  2.227622  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
  2.227651  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
  3.566194 89.69.145.76 -> 192.168.7.2  UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 11.640422  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 13.809216 89.69.145.76 -> 192.168.7.2  UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
Wed Jul 29 14:43:02 2015 read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (code=111)
 21.876795  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
Wed Jul 29 14:43:12 2015 read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (code=111)
 32.116168  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
Wed Jul 29 14:43:22 2015 NOTE: --mute triggered...
 42.283532  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 42.283564  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
Wed Jul 29 14:43:24 2015 2 variation(s) on previous 2 message(s) suppressed by --mute
Wed Jul 29 14:43:24 2015 Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Wed Jul 29 14:43:24 2015 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Wed Jul 29 14:43:26 2015 Re-using pre-shared static key
Wed Jul 29 14:43:26 2015 LZO compression initialized
Wed Jul 29 14:43:27 2015 Preserving previous TUN/TAP instance: tun0
Wed Jul 29 14:43:27 2015 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]:1195
Wed Jul 29 14:43:27 2015 UDPv4 link remote: 89.69.145.76:1195
Wed Jul 29 14:43:27 2015 read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (code=111)
Wed Jul 29 14:43:27 2015 read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (code=111)
 46.575799  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 46.575822  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
Wed Jul 29 14:43:31 2015 NOTE: --mute triggered...
 51.283850  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 57.386083  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 66.606426  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 66.606450  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
Wed Jul 29 14:43:58 2015 4 variation(s) on previous 2 message(s) suppressed by --mute
Wed Jul 29 14:43:58 2015 Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Wed Jul 29 14:43:58 2015 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
 79.480353  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
Wed Jul 29 14:44:00 2015 Re-using pre-shared static key
Wed Jul 29 14:44:00 2015 LZO compression initialized
Wed Jul 29 14:44:00 2015 Preserving previous TUN/TAP instance: tun0
Wed Jul 29 14:44:00 2015 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]:1195
Wed Jul 29 14:44:00 2015 UDPv4 link remote: 89.69.145.76:1195
Wed Jul 29 14:44:00 2015 read UDPv4 [ECONNREFUSED]: Connection refused (code=111)
Wed Jul 29 14:44:10 2015 Peer Connection Initiated with 89.69.145.76:1195
 89.588295  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 89.588321  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 89.680566 89.69.145.76 -> 192.168.7.2  UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
Wed Jul 29 14:44:11 2015 Initialization Sequence Completed
 92.180902 89.69.145.76 -> 192.168.7.2  UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 92.181072  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 92.405420 89.69.145.76 -> 192.168.7.2  UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 92.405643  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 92.409120 89.69.145.76 -> 192.168.7.2  UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 92.409194  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 92.501167 89.69.145.76 -> 192.168.7.2  UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 92.501909  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 92.504901 89.69.145.76 -> 192.168.7.2  UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
 92.505027  192.168.7.2 -> 89.69.145.76 UDP Source port: 1195  Destination port: 1195
```

Both client and server are behind nat, both have dynamic public IP addresses.
There is also a port forwarding (1195) on the router which connects server with the "World".

Router config - server side:

[image: Router config]

Router config, port forwarding - server side:

[image: port forwarding]

Router config - client side:

[image: Client side router]

Conntrack client side:

```
udp      17 179 src=192.168.7.2 dst=89.69.145.76 sport=1195 dport=1195 packets=852493 bytes=480026440 src=89.69.145.76 dst=192.168.7.2 sport=1195 dport=1195 packets=1093350 bytes=1226684584 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
```